# How to reference to member of public partial class MainWindow : Window from other static class?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
```

Also I have got some static class which does logging.

WHich the best way to refer/pass **MainWindow**  to that static class is?

Comment: Is the logging class called from within MainWindow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Application.Current.MainWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.current%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) to access main window elsewhere in your application.

Comment: Do u mean (MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow).SomeMember

Comment: yeah, something like that if you're trying to get to one of its members. Don't forget the extra '(' in the beginning.